# Problem with condition and two change event for inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with a condition and a change event for two inputs. When a change occurs to one of the two inputs, I will check the condition if the two have a value equal to 0, and if it does not, but when the change condition occurs on the two inputs simultaneously and the first is equal to 0, the first event will be executed within the first condition. The second event will be executed within the first condition as well, which must executed within the second condition.

> 

```js
$('.SH-SortByPrice').click(function(){
    $('.SH-PriceMaxSel').val(0).trigger('change');
    $('.SH-PriceMinSel').val(300).trigger('change');
});

$('.SH-PriceMinSel').change(function(){
    Selcted_chick_Pr();
});

$('.SH-PriceMaxSel').change(function(){
     Selcted_chick_Pr();
});

function Selcted_chick_Pr(){

    if(($('.SH-PriceMinSel').val() <= 0) && ($('.SH-PriceMaxSel').val() <= 0)){
          //first execution 
        }else{
          //second  execution 
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="PriceMaxSel" class="SH-PriceMaxSel" value="0">
        <input name="PriceMinSel" class="SH-PriceMinSel" value="0">
        <button class="SH-SortByPrice"  >
            <span>execution</span>
        </button>
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: when i click on 'SH-SortByPrice' fire the two change event and   execute Selcted_chick_Pr() two times , so the problem is with condition inside function when i put the values 0 in '.SH-PriceMaxSel'  and any other number in '.SH-PriceMinSel', i need make first and second execution for Selcted_chick_Pr() function use else condition.